# How to change a array of object inside a object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, spread

I have an object that contain a property with an array of objects which I have to change one object.

```
{id: '3688aa8f-e725-45f4-9513-363a1c019b34',
 category: 'Entertainment: Film',
 difficulty: 'easy',
 question: "What is the orange and white bot's name in &quot;Star Wars: The Force Awakens&quot;?",
  answers: [ 
    {id: 'da42762a-e936-42d8-ae61-2a0de53d3c5e', incorrect_answer: 'Austria', isSelected: false}, 
    {id: '44d8549f-31a7-4cdd-8a6b-80cf6a1b853c', incorrect_answer: 'Armenia', isSelected: false},
    {id: '2f734291-b4cf-48a0-8e54-3379b7d23ecb', incorrect_answer: 'Australia', isSelected: false},
    {id: 'dfa6fa70-3b44-44fe-b80a-fc9da72a6c7f', incorrect_answer: 'Afghanistan', isSelected: false}
   ]
}
```

How can I iterate over the `answers` array and change the property `isSelected` to `true`?

I am trying to use the spread operator, but its not working.

Comment: Maybe use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object using the id in the condition, and then update the other value?

Comment: How are you trying the [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator?

Comment: try `yourObj.answers.forEach(e => e.isSelected = true)`

Comment: Is this stored in react state? Because if so, the above comments would break the rules of react in regards to immutability.

Comment: @lharby map return value must be the whole item object and not only `e.isSelected = true`

Answer (score 0):

**Spread Operator Solution**

as @adsy mentioned with this solution you will lose the object reference to the answers item if its used somewhere else in your app. The spread operator  will create a new object of the array item.

```js
const obj = {id: '3688aa8f-e725-45f4-9513-363a1c019b34',
 category: 'Entertainment: Film',
 difficulty: 'easy',
 question: "What is the orange and white bot's name in &quot;Star Wars: The Force Awakens&quot;?",
  answers: [ 
    {id: 'da42762a-e936-42d8-ae61-2a0de53d3c5e', incorrect_answer: 'Austria', isSelected: false}, 
    {id: '44d8549f-31a7-4cdd-8a6b-80cf6a1b853c', incorrect_answer: 'Armenia', isSelected: false},
    {id: '2f734291-b4cf-48a0-8e54-3379b7d23ecb', incorrect_answer: 'Australia', isSelected: false},
    {id: 'dfa6fa70-3b44-44fe-b80a-fc9da72a6c7f', incorrect_answer: 'Afghanistan', isSelected: false}
   ]
};

obj.answers = obj.answers.map(e => ({...e, isSelected: true}));
console.log(obj.answers);
```

**forEach Solution**

```js
const obj = {id: '3688aa8f-e725-45f4-9513-363a1c019b34',
 category: 'Entertainment: Film',
 difficulty: 'easy',
 question: "What is the orange and white bot's name in &quot;Star Wars: The Force Awakens&quot;?",
  answers: [ 
    {id: 'da42762a-e936-42d8-ae61-2a0de53d3c5e', incorrect_answer: 'Austria', isSelected: false}, 
    {id: '44d8549f-31a7-4cdd-8a6b-80cf6a1b853c', incorrect_answer: 'Armenia', isSelected: false},
    {id: '2f734291-b4cf-48a0-8e54-3379b7d23ecb', incorrect_answer: 'Australia', isSelected: false},
    {id: 'dfa6fa70-3b44-44fe-b80a-fc9da72a6c7f', incorrect_answer: 'Afghanistan', isSelected: false}
   ]
};

obj.answers.forEach(e => e.isSelected = true);
console.log(obj.answers);
```

Comment: I think this is still potentially problematic as `answers` is still mutated. Though the way of mapping over it is cleaner than mine. If you adopt my approach but also use your use of `map`  it'd be the best answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Since your post is tagged with React, it's additionally important (if this object is contained within React state) to do this in a way that does not mutate the original structure, but instead, creates a new structure with the desired edit.

For the sake of example, I'm going to assume it's stored in some react state I've called `obj`.

```
const setAnswerIsSelected = (idToChange, isSelected) => {
    setObj(prevObj => ({
        ...prevObj,
        answers: [
          { ...prevObj.find(({id}) => id === idToChange), isSelected },
          ...prevObj.filter(({id}) => id !== idToChange) 
        ]
    }))

}
```

Just getting the answer object itself and mutating it is not a good idea if this is in React state as doing so is not allowed in React.

Deep updates can be cumbersome. Changing the state structure to be flatter and spread across multiple items can alleviate this. Or use something like Immer.

Comment: Thanks Adsy for the advice. Actually the data is more cumbersome than this because which object of data like is inside of another array.
I will take your advice and change the state structure.